# Modelling "services" in a uml class diagram

Tags: class, uml, diagram

In one on my software engineering homework i need to make the class diagram for modelling the problem of develop a system for a public library that can manage its **loan service**.

In this scenario i have an **user**, that can loan trough a **loan service** some library material (like audio dvd, video, text like book or something else).
This is the rapid blueprint:
[image: ciao]
Now my questions are:

**Q1**: How can i model the association between user and the loan service? and , exactly, what is the name of this association?

**Q2**: The loan service class only have one istance, because i think that the service is global for all user, so is correct to modelling this in the cardinality of the association?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: What does "modelling the problem of develop a system" mean? Are you supposed to model the problem domain or to model the solution? A class diagram can serve many purposes and the answers to your questions depend on the purpose. If you share the exact original text of the homework assignment, it may be more clear what you're supposed to do.

Comment: I think is problem domain solution,
the text isn't so clear but basically there is a high level user requirement text,
and the exercise are:
1)elaborate the text in more detailed and usefull analysis
2)make some important use cases
3)make some important activity diagram
4)make a class diagram.

So i think model the domain problem?

Comment: Yes, apparently you are asked to model the problem domain. In that case, don't model the LoanService, since it is part of the solution domain.

Comment: So, instead of model a LoanService, that describe "who" and "how" the Loan is managed, i need to insert a Loan class for describe the general concept of loan in the problem domain? 
Thank's for answer

Comment: Yes. To model how a loan is managed, you use use cases and activity diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are to make an information model for the business operations of an organization (in your case, a public library), you have to identify all entity types involved (e.g., users, media types, media items such as books and DVDs, loans, reservations, etc.) and the associations between them (e.g., the class `User` would be associated with `Loan`).

But you don't include a class for the organization itself (or its information system) in the model. Consequently, do not include a class for "loan service".

This approach results in an ***information design model*** that is the basis for deriving both an *OOP class model* for defining *model classes* (also called *entity classes*) and a *database table model* (e.g., for defining a MySQL database schema).

***The model/entity classes provide the foundation for your app or IS.***

Depending on your app development approach (e.g., the chosen framework), you may have to design other classes (e.g., for the user interface), but, compared to the model/entity classes, they are less fundamental.

Comment: Hi, thank's for answer!
ok that is what i was wondering,
i mustn't model who provides a service but the "service" itself.

But, in this case, if i replace LoanService with a Loan class,
who made the action of make a Loan? 
is the Loan itself that can "make a loan" or the user that can "make a loan"

Comment: And another question, what an association modelling exactly? when i put an association between two class, how this is traslate in design and coding? a communication access? @Gerd Wagner

Comment: @artas Associations will translate in object references in code. Anyhow, don't start a Q/A in comments. Rather create a new question if needed.